# Using AMPScript loop for generating content in an Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have defined a Generic Template Email using AMPScript.

So all the content will be dynamically included when sending the Email.

I am using LOOP sentences in my AMPSCript code.

When sending these emails manually, no issue at all.

When including these emails inside a Journey, I started to have some issues and received some automatic recommendations to use different @i variable name for the LOOPS. So, I have modified my code and used a specific @VarCounter for every loop.

The thing is that even after using a different Counter var name for every loop I am having the same issue.

How can I solve it ?

The error message is:

```
"*--- inner exception 1---
ExactTarget.OMM.OMMException: An error occurred when attempting to parse HtmlEmailBody content for HTML content.
MemberID: xxxxxxx
JobID: xxxxx
ListID: xx
--- inner exception 4---
System.InvalidOperationException: The FOR statement counter variable @ModuleImageHTML_Counter is already in use in this scope. Please pick a distinct variable name. - from OMMCommon
Once the Triggered Send is ready to start sending again, you can restart it in Email Studio via the Interactions tab, click on Messages >> Email >> Triggered Sends (or respective folder the Triggered Send may reside in), check the box next to the Triggered Send referenced and click on “Start/Restart.” Please note -- until you restart the Triggered Send, it will remain in a paused state.*
"
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Hi Jonas, there is no complexity in the code. Just a For loop.

Comment: Please share the ampscript code, to allow us review it and help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that you are attempting to modify (or 'set') the counter variable. The counter variable is locked from modification within a process loop. Any attempt to declare it will result in a validation or runtime error.

I'm assuming your loop looks something like:

```js
%%[

var @ModuleImageHTML_Counter
set @ModuleImageHTML_Counter = 2

for @VarCounter = 1 to 5 do

set @VarCounter = @ModuleImageHTML_Counter /* NOT allowed */

   /* other stuff here */

next
]%%
```

You can't set `@ModuleImageHTML_Counter` within the loop. And you shouldn't need to either. I can't think of any scenario where you would either need to or want to modify the counter variable.

In the above code, the process loop statement is effectively saying *"set @VarCounter to 1 as the starting index, and continue looping until the end index expression of 5 is reached"*.

The next keyword closes the for loop. When the next keyword is reached, the system compares the end index expression to the value of the counter variable. If the value is not equal to the end index, the loop will repeat, and increment `@VarCounter` by 1, until the end index is reached.

As Jonas points out, without looking at your code it's hard to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve, but you shouldn't need to modify the counter variable.

Comment: Thanks Eliot for your reply ! You are right ! It was related with your answer. I have in my code two for loops sentences in a row and as they are sharing the same scope, apparently they are sometimes running racing conditions. So I solved the issue declaring different @counter var names. Thanks again !

Comment: Glad I could help! Please can you accept my answer, for the benefit of others?